# One Tomcat instance for two domains and two webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, dns

How can I configure Tomcat (in standalone mode, that is **without Apache** [*]) so that I can deploy it on one server and have it serve two different webapps, depending on the domain name requested?

What are the gotchas when doing that?  Can you have SSL on both domains?  If anyone here actually did it I'd be interested in answer to these questions as well as as much feedback as possible...

I found a blog entry describing such a setup, but it's for Tomcat 5.5:

```
<Engine defaultHost="domain1.com" name="Catalina">
    <Host name="domain1.com" appBase="/home/user1/domain1">
     <Alias>www.domain1.com</Alias>
     <Context path="" docBase="."/>
    </Host>
    <Host name="domain2.com" appBase="/home/user1/domain2">
     <Alias>www.domain2.com</Alias>
     <Context path="" docBase="."/>
    </Host>
```

http://iam-rakesh.blogspot.com/2009/10/hosting-multiple-domains-in-tomcat.html

Also, as of now I've got one webapp, ROOT.war, inside .../tomcat/webapps/

How would that work once I'd have two "roots", one root webapp for *domain1.com* and one root webapp for *domain2.com?*  Where would the *.war* needs to be located?

Comment: [*] I know it can be done relatively easily using Apache in front of Tomcat...  But this is not what this question is about.  This question is really about doing such a thing with Tomcat in standalone mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog that you linked to basically shows how to do it. The one thing that you need to differently is to set the 'docBase' attribute differently for each host.  The docBase is the location of war files for that host. With different docBases, you can have different root apps.